# How to play .wav file from URL in web browser embed - Java

Tags: java, audio, embed, wav

I want to play a .wav sound file in embed default media player in IE. Sound file is on some HTTP location. I am unable to sound it in that player.

Following is the code.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.concidel.com/upload/myfile.wav");
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = (InputStream)urlc.getInputStream();
         fileBytes = new byte[is.available()];
         while (is.read(fileBytes,0,fileBytes.length)!=-1){}
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
         out.write(fileBytes);
```

Here is embed code of HTML.

```
<embed src="CallStatesTreeAction.do?ivrCallId=${requestScope.vo.callId}&agentId=${requestScope.vo.agentId}" type="application/x-mplayer2" autostart="0" playcount="1" style="width: 40%; height: 45" />
```

1. If I write in FileOutputStream then it plays well
2. If I replace my code of getting file from URL to my local hard disk. then it also works fine.

I don't know why I am unable to play file from HTTP. And why it plays well from local hard disk.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the correct response type. IE is very picky in that regard.

[EDIT] Your copy loop is broken. Try this code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.concidel.com/upload/myfile.wav");
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = (InputStream)urlc.getInputStream();
fileBytes = new byte[is.available()];
int len;
while ( (len = is.read(fileBytes,0,fileBytes.length)) !=-1){
    response.getOutputStream.write(fileBytes, 0, len);
}
```

The problem with your code is: If the data isn't fetched in a single call to `is.read()`, it's not appended to `fileBytes` but instead the first bytes are overwritten.

Also, the output stream which you get from the response is already buffered.

Comment: Check my edits. To be sure, save the data also to a file (not only to the response) and try to play that file (to test that it was not corrupted).